# How to add relation to existing object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add relation between existing post and author.

I was trying to modify `created_by` attribute but it's not accessible from object.

```
def set_author
    if (@post.created_by.empty? && @post.author_code.present?)
      if @post.author_code == params[:author_code]
        @post.created_by = current_user
      else
        raise(ExceptionHandler::InvalidAuthorCode, Message.invalid_author_code)
      end
    else
      raise(ExceptionHandler::DisallowedAction, Message.action_not_allowed)
  end
end
```

It's not working because there is no method `@post.created_by` even if it's present db.
Post model from schema.rb

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"  
  t.text "content"
  t.boolean "accepted", default: false
  t.string "created_by"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.string "author_code"
end
```

Edit: 
part of post.rb

```
  belongs_to :user, optional: true, foreign_key: :created_by
```

part of user.rb

```
  has_many :confessions, foreign_key: :created_by
```

Comment: How did you create `created_by`? Using migration or by using query?

Comment: In migration. It was created in same time as post model.

Comment: Just answered, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it only fails for the `@post` which don't have any `created_by OR user` then you can use following:

```
@post.try(:created_by).blank? && @post.author_code.present?
```

Comment: partially solved my problem, because there were probably 2 mistakes in my code

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to update @post attributes a wrong way. Changed

```
@post.created_by = current_user
```

to

```
@post.update_attribute(:created_by, current_user)
```

and it's working.
It's not a Devise user model, just self written.